# Derivative of shadow price in LP objective coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the standard LP with value function
\begin{equation}
  \Omega(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}) = \max_{\mathbf{x}} \left\{\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x} \,|\, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}\right\}
\end{equation}
and given parameters of suitable dimensions. Supposing primal non-degeneracy, we know the $k$-th Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_k = \partial \Omega / \partial b_k$ has the shadow price interpretation.

Are there any general results about $\partial \lambda_k / \partial c_\ell$, perhaps under additional assumptions about the parameters?

Comment: Let $z=\textbf{cx}$ the profit of $n$ products with $m$ constraints, where $1\leq k\leq m$. If you raise the bound $b_k$ by one unit, then the optimal value $z^*$ raises by $\lambda_k$. I can post an example if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I have already noted this in the question.

Comment: Sorry .  I don't see that any additional assumption has to be made.

Comment: You seem to answer a different question than I asked: I am interested in the derivative of $\lambda_k$ in the $\ell$-th coefficient in $\mathbf{c}$ of the value function $\Omega$.